# Generating String from Excel Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel with three columns and three rows like below:

```
Field1,Field2,Field3

Row1Value1,Row1Value2,Row1Value3

Row2Value1,Row2Value2,Row2Value3

Row3Value1,Row3Value2,Row3Value3
```

I want to write a VBA Macro to generate an output like below:

```
Field1=Row1Value1,Field2=Row1Value2,Field3=Row1Value3
Field1=Row2Value1,Field2=Row2Value2,Field3=Row2Value3
Field1=Row3Value1,Field2=Row3Value2,Field3=Row3Value3
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Please share any code that you have written so far in an attempt to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could do it very simply in VBA (we can help you out after you've shared an attempt). If you just want the end result, it would be quicker for you to do with a basic (non-VBA) formula in the sheet.

```
= A$1 & "=" & B1 & "," & A$2 & "=" & B2 & "," & A$3 & "=" & B3
```

(Assuming your top left cell in the table is A1)

Comment: Yes I am new to VBA so struggling a bit. Trying to figure out how to iterate through each row and column and also how to figure out the # of rows and # of column.

Comment: I can do it using formula - but if the column number changes I have to add to formula, which is ok for now. I am working on a sample that I will post

Comment: That'd be great. Will the number and position of columns and rows you want to include in the string change then?

Answer (score 1):

Think I got it working:

```
Sub Transform()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
For i = 2 To Worksheets("Input").UsedRange.Rows.Count
Dim row As String
    row = ""
    For j = 1 To Worksheets("Input").UsedRange.Columns.Count
        row = row & Worksheets("Input").Cells(1, j) & "=" & Worksheets("Input").Cells(i, j) & ","

    Next j
    Worksheets("Result").Cells(i, 1) = Left(row, Len(row) - 1)
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: That should work fine, although as a warning be careful with UsedRange.Rows/Columns.Count as it also counts rows which have been added and then cleared (rather than deleted).